# Kinect fast hand tracking method

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

How can I track fast hand movement using kinect?
I've tried both Openni and Microsoft sdk to track hand. On both of them, there are lots of jitters and inaccurate movement of joints.

Here is an example video of kinect fruit ninja: [Example Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8Osemh24BQ)

On that video, there are no jitters and inaccuracy and also it's tracking the fast hand movements.

What am I missing? Is there any kinds of kinect hardware versions or types which I should look into.

Comment: We can not know what you are missing if you do not include what you've tried.  Microsoft Kinect SDK comes with smoothing algorithms built in, OpenNI may also have them.  Please update your question and include code that you have a specific question about -- we can look at it and then give ideas on how to adjust it so your tracking is cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that Fruit Ninja applies some sort of smoothing at some point. What you're seeing in that video is almost certainly not the raw data they're getting from the Kinect. The data from the Kinect will always have some kind of jitter; real-world sensor data almost always does. You'll need to smooth it - exactly how to do that depends on the application; it could be something simple like modelling a kind of damping and/or inertia on the point that's being moved by the hand (which is what I suspect Fruit Ninja is doing), or you could look at something like a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) for a robust (but more computationally-intensive) way to reduce the noise in your sensor readings.