# Kinect - Refinement of segmented hand region

Tags: kinect, image-segmentation

I am aiming to recognize gestures with Kinect, then I began with the extraction of hand region using a depth image, based on [Finger/Hand Gesture Recognition using Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777821/finger-hand-gesture-recognition-using-kinect).

As a result, I get the hand region with part of the arm [image: my image]
.

I ask You:

1. How the hand region could be refined in order to obtain it only from the wrist?
2. What would be the easy way to obtain the hand palm region?

Thanks in advance. Other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Hi Outlaw Lemur, I loaded the image with the segmentation. As You can see it requires to draw out the arm part.

Comment: Hmm... What about when your hand is open

Comment: Is very similar : http://i58.tinypic.com/fkqfb9.png

Comment: I am using a depth threshold around the hand center, but in general  some pixels of the arm could have closer depth. What could I use to solve my problem?, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using the pose models that Kinect comes with. It provides a [skeleton model](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~chang/153/kinectIntro.html) where it tracks each person in view. From this model, i think you should be able to extract the hand positions [already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171730/kinect-fast-hand-tracking-method). Look [here](http://cvrlcode.ics.forth.gr/handtracking/) for a more strict model that separates articulated hand motion, which also involves basic hand tracking.